# How to make my text go to top in a container

Tags: flutter

I want to make my output like this:

1. ahjskdgad
2. asdhadada
3. asdhasuidhad
4. adhauishda
   saidjajiasdasd
5. asodhasdhasid
   isdoaoisdhas
   asodhasodh

Code:

```
Container(
      width: 300,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 10,
                child: Text(
                  '4.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 290,
                child: Text(
                  'I hereby acknowledge and consent that company shall provide me with the information only through a durable medium, (i.e., any instrument which enables a client to store information for future reference and adequate period, and allows the unchanged reproduction of the information stored.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 10,
                child: Text(
                  '5.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 290,
                child: Text(
                  'You agree that company may collect, use and disclose your personal data which you have provided in this form, for providing marketing material that you have agreed to receive, in accordance with Privacy Policy.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: please format the code, rewrite the question, see how to write a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if this what you are trying to achieve,
Just add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` in the row.